# Where to maintain the cache in application

Tags: java, caching

Hello In my web application I am maintaining list of URL authorized for user in a HashMap and compare the requested URL and revert as per the authorization. This Map has Role as key and URLs as value in form of List. My problem is where I should have this Map?

In Session: It may have hundreds of URLs and that can increase the burden of session.

In Cache at Application loading: The URLs may get modified on the fly and then I need to resync it by starting server again.

In Cache that update periodically: Application level Cache that will update periodically.

I require a well optimized approach that can serve the purpose, help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm preferring to make it as a singleton Class and Have a thread that updates it periodically .. The thread will maintain the state of the cache .. this thread will be started when you get the fist instance of the cache

```
public class CacheSingleton {
   private static CacheSingleton instance = null;
   private HashMap<String,Role> authMap;
   protected CacheSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
      // Start the thread to maintain Your map
   }
   public static CacheSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new CacheSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   // Add your cache logic here
   // Like getRole,checkURL() ... etc 

}
```

wherever in your code you can get the cached data

```
CacheSingleton.getInstance().yourMethod();
```